# Why do bats huddle during late fall?

Tags: physiology, homework

In the late fall, bats hibernate in clusters with many bats pressed together and holding on to one another. Which of the following supposed advantages of huddling behavior is, in reality, not true?

1. Any heat generated by any bat is shared by other bats.
2. Less surface area is exposed to the environment.
3. Huddling behavior decreases the amount of food needed for bats to stay warm.
4. In this configuration, less heat is needed for each bat and, therefore, each bat requires less food.
5. Huddling behavior helps bats stay warm while they feed.

Comment: this looks like a homework question!  we don't play that here.

Comment: @shigeta she _did_ actually tag it as homework.

Comment: Think about where/when bats huddle, where/how/when they feed.

Comment: @biogirl What do you think? What's your reasoning so far?

Comment: ok fair enough.  still this seems like a hard one to help with.  'one of these things is not like the other' is about all i would say.

Comment: @kmm I think huddling helps them stay warm but the answer given in book is 5th. I think 3rd and 4th say the same thing and 1st and 2nd are definitely true.So only 5th can be the answer but I think huddling behavior does help in staying warm .

Comment: Huddling behaviour can help in staying warm, but think about @terdons comment some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a trick question and a bit of a cheap shot. All of the reasons cited boil down to "bats huddle to conserve heat", they are basically the same, single, reason.

In order for bats to feed, they need to move, fly out of their cave or wherever they happen to sleep and go forth and look for food. Therefore, they will not be able to huddle while feeding because they will be flying around trying to find fruit or donkeys or whatever each species feeds on. Unless they can figure out a way to huddle while flying, they will not be able to huddle while feeding and so number 5 is wrong.